# Tallying words in a string in Java

Tags: java, string, compare

Consider the line of code below;

```
String one = "the cow jumped over the other cow";
```

Is there a way to test if:

> `cow` appears twice in the sentence?
>
> `jumped` and `cow` appear in the sentence(regardless of order)?

I only ask because I am currently working on a poker program that spits out hands in the form of strings (by way to the ArrayList.toString() method)  and i wanted to make a method that reads the strings a derives what kind of hand it is, and assigns it a value based on the hand.  I want to do this without going through every single combination of a hand.

Comment: Yes.  Look at the String.split method.

Comment: Can you use an example with your actual poker values instead of cows and jumps?

Comment: well, for example one hand looks like this:  [1. Jack of spades, 2. queen of spades, 3. three of hearts, 4. four of diamonds, 5. three of spades]  and i'm trying to test for multiple 'spades'  ie.  if there are 5 spades,  he was a full house, or if there two threes, he has a pair, etc

Comment: In general, one would likely want a Map<String, Integer> if we talk Java for the task you talk about.  Too complex perhaps for your problem, depends how you handle it.  The Counter in Python is a good example of an implementation of this data structure.